# Spivak's fuzzy simplicial set

Tags: category-theory

I am reading https://math.mit.edu/%7Edspivak/files/metric_realization.pdf and I am unsure about the following (on page 4) where it says:

"We are ready to define $Re$ on a general $X$ as
$$Re(X) := colim_{\Delta_{<a}^n →X} Re(∆_{<a}^n)$$

This functor preserves colimits, so it has a right adjoint..."

$Re$ is the realization functor $Re: sFuz → UM$ where $sFuz$ is the category of fuzzy simplicial sets and $UM$ is the category of uber-metric spaces. $∆_{<a}^n ∈ sFuz$ denote the functor represented by $(n,[0,a))$.

Questions:

1. Could somebody explain me the notation: $colim_{\Delta_{<a}^n →X} Re(∆_{<a}^n)$ and its meaning? I know what colimits are (and some examples). This seems to be kind of a "gluing" I guess.
2. Does $Re(X)$ definition imply that $Re$ preserves colimits? This is clearly related to Question 1.
3. Why the fact that it preserve colimits implies that it has a right adjoint? This is maybe using a version of the Adjoint Functor Theorem. However, there are some other things that need to be satisfied to use this Theorem, which I don't find obvious that $UM$ satisfies. Maybe $$\text{Lemma } 2.2. \text{The category UM is closed under colimits.}$$ has something to do?

I know these are not easy questions so I would greatly appreciate the guidance.

Thanks a lot!